# How to print the last value of my output in perl?

Tags: perl

I wrote a script which, for the first time, works as I want :P  I will provide my script below. The only thing that I wish to do, and I didn't succeed, was to print ONLY the last value of my output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = '/home/Desktop/my_scripts/coordinates_based';

my $p;
my $i;
my $mikos = 0;
my $sum = 0;
my $count = 1;
my $mikos_thetika = 0;
my $mikos_arnitika = 0;
my $k = 1;
my @table = ();
my $final = 0;
my $neg = 0;
my $pos = 0;
my $size;
my $last_value = 0;

open(FH, '<', $filename) or die $!;

while (<FH>) {

    my ($n, $p, $a, $b) = split '\s+';

    chomp;
    $i =  1 if $p eq '+';
    $i = -1 if $p eq '-';

    for ($k..$n)
    {
        $mikos = $b - $a;
        if ($p eq '+')
        {
            $mikos_thetika = $mikos*1 ;
            $pos += $mikos_thetika;
        }
        else
        {
            $mikos_arnitika = $mikos*(-1);
            $neg += $mikos_arnitika;
        }

        $final = $pos + $neg;

        #chomp;
        #push(@table, $final);

        #$size = scalar @table;
        say $final;

        $k = $k + 1;
    }
}
close(FH);
```

**Script explanation :** the output calculates the difference between $b and $a and based on $p print its difference with the - or + respectively. And at the end prints the sum of those difference but not in total as I want but as a sum ($final) of previous value with the coming one.

I tried these:

```
1)  if ($k==$n) # $n is first column of my input file
    {$last_value =$table[$k];}
    say $last_value; # But it prints the same output.

2)  $size= scalar @table;
    $last_value = $table [$size];
    say $size; # prints the correct table size but not as value 
               # but as an entire sequence. For example 
               # if my table size is 5 it prints 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n 5

3) # Also i tried the List library 
    use List::Util qw(sum);
    $last_value=sum($final);
```

input file :

```
$n $p $a $b   
1 - 852 1934
2 - 2020 3108
3 + 3212 3781
4 - 3917 4162
5 - 4263 4421
```

output file after my script

```
-1082
-2170
-1601
-1846
-2004
```

Desired output

```
2004
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you need but often it's good enough to print the thing of interest right after the loop, so you get the value from the last iteration.  (Also, it says "_output file after my script_" but the code you show doesn't print to file?)

Comment: Can you not indent that code nicely?  This makes it harder for people to help you out.

Comment: im sorry about that but im totally amateur in perl. I know that my code needs improvements. Regarding the title I dont know if I can edit it. Maybe I didn't address the question properly.

Comment: Well .. it's not about Perl, just common code indentation. Have you worked with any code, any language?  (You click the "edit" button right below and then edit it all you want :)

Comment: no unfortunately. I have zero experience in informatics. I can understand your frustration about my code "presentation," and this is why I tried to be as much as  analytical i can.

Comment: Thank you for responding -- I didn't mean to show frustration, sorry :)  I fixed the indentation and added some spaces around as customary.  If you don't like it you can "roll back" the whole thing to how it was (go to "edited ..." link right above my username and you'll see versions, where you can roll back). Otherwise you can edit as you wish of course.

Comment: As for my first comment -- I meant that if you move that `say $final;` after the `while` loop (so on a line after its closing paren) then it will print only the last thing from `for ($k..$n)` for the last line in `while (<FH>)`, because that is what is going to be in that `$final` after the loop. Is that what you need?  Or, you can collect what you want into an array as you go along, not printing anything, and then after all loops print what you want to print.

Comment: no it is fine by me. Every comments end especially corrections are welcome. It is good to have a better virtualisation of the correct way of how my script should be. About your suggested correction I will try the say $final and I will see If I get what I want. Thank you soo much for the corrections :D

Comment: @Zdim It works as I want, and I think I get why my output keeps printing the  $final many times. Thanks alot

Comment: Great :)  This is really good for a begining effort :).  A few comments follow

Comment: The `split` has a special pattern: `split ' ', $str` -- the `' '` (space) means `\s+` _and_ the leading space at the beginning of `$str` is removed.  Very handy!  This is also its default, so for `split ' ', $_` you can write just `split`.  It's a bit of an idiom, too, and it fits precisely what you are doing, so  `my ($n, $p, $a, $b) = split;`. (Note this works because no variable is defined in the `while (...)` so `$_` is indeed assigned what `<FH>` reads.)  See documentation for [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: It's better to use _lexical filehandles_, `open my $fh, ...`.  Just _better_ than typeglobs (`FH` etc)

Comment: "Empty" initialization when declaring arrays (or hashes) like `my @ary = ();` does precisely nothing more than just `my @ary;`.  (It is useful for clearing an array when needed in the program, like `@ary = ();`,  but that's different.)

Comment: The notion of [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) is very important in Perl, and it's used everywhere, and rather fluidly.  Example: when you assign an array to a scalar variable it's the size of the array that gets assigned, because the assignment itself (`=` operator) is in _scalar context_.  So in `$size = @table;` the size of `@table` is what `$size` gets.  So absolutely no need for `scalar` (a commented-out line in the code).

Comment: Thank you once again for your comments. Regarding the "when you assign an array comment that you gave me," to be fair, I was not sure 100% about what I am doing and if it is Perl "legit." As I aimed to print the last value of my output file, I tried to specify this value by adding output's values in an array and afterwards to "point" array's position by selecting the value this row, which in my case is equal with arrays length. That was the only logical point that I think to define it. I didnt expect to be so "Perl" strict :P  So the solution was much simpler as you explained me :-)

Comment: I have a last question if you dont mind.  When you are using the brackets did you press "tab" every time you open like one tab for the first "for" double tab for the first "if" etc??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have this situation, where at the end of each iteration
you output something. You keep doing this because you don't know when you'll
get to the last element.

```
while( <FH> ) {
    say $_ ** 2;
    }
```

Instead of outputting something, save the result for output later. When
you run into another element, replace that value. When you run out of
input, the last value that you remembered is the value that you want to 
output:

```
my $previous_output;
while( <FH> ) {
    $previous_output = $i ** 2;
    }

say $previous_output;
```

Or, you can cheat by making all of the output and grabbing just the last line with `tail` (or something similar):

```
% perl script.pl | tail -n 1
```

Comment: I see your point. I got the same answer from @Zdim too. To be fair I knew about the "cheating" you proposed but as I have zero experience in programming languages I decided to wrote this script to start learning somehow :P. Thanks  for your answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I took some liberty to *clean up* your code.

Please see if you find the following code snippet easier to read/understand than your original.

It serves same purpose/function as your original code, except per your request output final result after all data processed right before program exits.

**Note:** zdim brought to my attention that code can be *improved* with [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) special case, `if ... else ...` CPU cycle efficiency (for sanitized input data) and regarding header skip code (header can be absent or have different format). Although initially I did not intended *to make improvement* of the code but only code *readability*, I consider zdim's suggestion a worthwhile change.

**Note:** input data sanitized with `next unless /\d+ +[+-] +\d+ +\d+/;` what might look somewhat unusual as normally it is written as `next unless /\d+\s+[+-]\s+\d+\s+\d+/;` -- it is more for demonstration purpose that same goal can be achieved in different ways. I assumed potential cases inconsistency of input data when data fields can be separated with more than one space (user could adjust spacing for readability). `' '` and `\s` is quite different as first assumes only ' ' (space) but '\s' assumes [ \f\n\r\t]. [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = 'coordinates_based';    # I run code in same directory as input file

my($k,$pos,$neg,$final);               # only necessary variables for computation 

$k = 1;
$pos = $neg = 0;                       # some variables initialization

open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Could not open $filename: $!";

while (<$fh>) {                             # walk through file
    next unless /\d+ +[+-] +\d+ +\d+/;      # sanitize input data
    chomp;

    my ($n, $p, $a, $b) = split;            # see split doc for special case

    for ($k..$n)
    {
        if ($p eq '+') {
            $pos += $b-$a;   # thetika  (positive)
        } else {
            $neg -= $b-$a;   # arnitika (negative)
        }

        $final = $pos + $neg;

        $k++;
    }
}

close $fh;

say $final;                            # output result of computation
```

Output

```
-2004
```

Comment: Since the stated purpose is to clean up the code (nice!), let me comment. (1) That `split '\s+';` should use the special pattern `' '` instead of `\s+`, and since that's the default then it's `... = split;`.  It's an idiom too.  (2) two statements test exclusive values for `$p`; it should be an `if-else` branch. (3) if you decide to condense their `$k = $k + 1` (reasonable I'd say) then why not go all the way, `++$k;`.  I didn't at all consider logic.  (These are just well-meant comments, and not criticism either.)

Comment: Also -- testing for a header at each line begs a comment. If the header is removed before the loop (void `<$fh>`), as it's common, then of course there's a problem when files have no header: how to test when we need to read first? (Easily solved but complicates the code.) However, I'd say that this absolutely need be commented on and considered, since it's usually known whether processed data files have a header line or not.  (Also, if we don't know even whether there is a header line then the test against `/\$n/` may not be quite conclusive either so we're back at being uncertain.)

Comment: @zdim -- my clean up meat for readability not so much on code improvement. I agree on `++$k` or `$k++`. If OP guarantees the input file will be kept as in sample then `if ... else ...` will work (it save a few CPU cycles but not much). I thought about _purifying_ input data with `next unless /\d\s+[+-]\s+\d+\s+\d+/;`. I kept `\s+` just in case if input data by an error will have more than one ` ` (space) separating fields (preserved from OP's original code). If OP can guaranty the input format then `next unless /\d [+-] \d+ \d+/` (/\d +[+-]+ +\d +\d/`) will do nicely as will `split ' '`.

Comment: @zdim -- main issue which can rise is inconsistency of input data, people tend to make mistakes unintentionally. Depending on terminal sometimes difficult to distinguish **is there one or two spaces**. What is even more problematic is that some _code user_ will decide to adjust numbers in columns for readability by adding extra spaces. It will make easier to read data file but regex doesn't take it in account (\s+ was left for this case as it is more flexible).

Comment: Sorry for not stating it, I assumed that you'd look at docs for `split` if you weren't aware of that special pattern --  that `' '` is `\s+`, and which also removes leading space

Comment: @zdim -- thank you for bringing my attention to `split` or `split ' '` as a special case. I was using it for a very long time (since first edition 'Learn Perl') in automatic _mode_, even do not remember if it always was removing leading space. Ok, I will adjust my answer with some code improvement (info block will be added with mentioning of this change).

Comment: @PolarBear First of all, thank you very much for your initiative to make my script more "clean". I just realized how many useless coding lines I used.  The problem in my case that Perl gives me warnings and asks me to define my values, so I define everything to be safe.  So I didn't know that I can set all in once like my($k,$pos,$neg,$final);  or decreasing the line codes in the $k++; case.  Last but not least,  reading your comment I understand the importance of  data sanitization at the begging of the script so thanks for that.  I hope one day to make my code looking so simple as yours.

Comment: @KGee -- Google is your friend, search for **perl bookshelf**, read the books and learn -- obtained knowledge will lasts for rest of your life.

Comment: @KGee -- I suggest you to read book [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/). Perl language is in constant **fluctuation** and adapts to new world requirements. The books which you will find in **perl bookshelf** a little behind of time and some new language construction has been proposed. **Modern Perl** covers this _ground_ and recommended for reading _to be on same foot with time_.

Comment: @KGee --  **Modern Perl** book available as pdf file in [letter](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/modern_perl_2016_letter.pdf) and [A4](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/modern_perl_2016_a4.pdf) formats. Feel free to print it if you prefer _real paper back copy_.

Comment: @PolarBear thank you very much for the book and generally for the entire help.